# Is there any way to do a Drop Shadow effect in XAML on a TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, formatting

I have a XAML TextBlock that I would like to render as a drop shadow.  That is a white layer of text on top of a black layer.  I'm doing this to make the text stand.  Currently I have two TextBlocks offset to the right and below by two pixels.  The top layer is white and the bottom layer is black.

Is there a simple way to do this in XAML?  If so can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bitmap effects are deprecated.  Use the new GPU-accelerated [DropShadowEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx) instead.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect />
    </TextBlock.Effect>
    Drop.
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Caution: when you use `DropShadowEffect`, you might run into [blurriness issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688384/wpf-dropshadoweffect-causing-blurriness).

Comment: Do you know the equivalent of this for windows 10 universal app?

Comment: @SiGanteng Nope.  Ask a new question, if nobody else has, for 10ua.

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextBlock
 Text="Shadow Text"
 Foreground="Teal">
<TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
<DropShadowBitmapEffect
  ShadowDepth="4"
  Direction="330"
  Color="Black"
  Opacity="0.5"
  Softness="0.25" />
</TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
</TextBlock>
```

There are plenty of other examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273.aspx)