# Shadow effect and blurry text

Tags: c#, wpf, shadow, effect, blurry

I would like to add shadows outside tiles in my WPF application, but when I do, the text inside tiles is blurry. I tried this solution: [WPF DropShadowEffect Causing Blurriness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688384/wpf-dropshadoweffect-causing-blurriness) , but unfortunately shadow effect seems not to work at all. Are there any special attributtes in Rectangle which should be set? Could you give me some clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the same issue and solved this by using `UseLayoutRounding="True"`

**EDIT**

```
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

  <Grid.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                        Color="Black"
                        BlurRadius="20" />
  </Grid.Effect>

  <!-- your content -->
  <Grid Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="20" Margin="10" />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

results this

[image]

hope that helps

Comment: @user2876704 mh, it could help me and others to post your xaml code

Comment: I think my code wouldn't make any difference. The problem is that your solutions don't work even if I put them in blank page/window.
1) There's shadow and so is blurring
2) No shadow, no blurring ;)

Comment: @user2876704 my mistake, i updated my answer to the working solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works, but if there is more elements with shadow on the page, UseLayoutRounding property should be set on a root element.